# Trying to import keras but got an error

Tags: python

Trying to import Keras 2.0.4 with Tensorflow 1.0.1 on Windows10 as backend, but I got the following message:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

I've recently upgraded my pandas into version 0.20.1, is it the reason why I failed to import keras?

There is a lot more information available on the error message. if you want to know about it, just let me know

Answer (score 3):

It was caused by updating to latest version of pandas (0.20.2). Updating dask package to the latest version (0.14.3) can resolve this issue.

```
$ conda update dask
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be resolved for now by using an older Pandas such as 0.19.2 or 0.19.1

```
python -m pip install pandas==0.19.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, solved it by installing an older pandas version
    `pip install pandas==0.19.2`